# \n \t Not working on PHP Version 5.2.17

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site that runs on PHP Version 5.2.17.

I've tried to export Excel file with data using `\n\t`,
but the file doesn't accept this tags and the export shows only the word "total".

My output:

```
$Output = "total\t" . count($home->leads) . "\n";
```

I'm using this headers:

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
```

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: To print the count($home->leads) and more of this output

Comment: How about using `<pre></pre>` so the browser can print the tab `\t` on screen not just in the sourcecode?

Comment: Do you want them in the same cell? Do you expect them to show in different cells? Do you expect total to act as a header of column? How should the end output look like exactly?

Comment: The output comes out as an attachment, so the browser wont render it anyway. Please, show where you actually output your `$Output`

Comment: And where are you checking your output? In excel directly? Or are you checking the actual contents of your response?

Comment: I'm trying to create them in different cells using tabs.

Comment: I'm checking the Excel directly and the content stops writing after the \t or \n tag.

Comment: Check the result in a text editor, to see your **real** output.

Comment: Found a post where someone explains the issue with \t and \n read here: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/dataexport/  look for `function cleanData`